# Python script with flask server takes too long to exit on Windows

Tags: python, windows, flask

I'm new to Python.
As a part of a project I'm trying to deploy a Flask server locally, through the Windows command line.

My Python version is 3.6.0.

#### The code:

```python
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/') def index():
    return '<h1>Hello World!</h1>'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

#### The problem:

It's about killing the script as it runs. Launching this script with `python deploy.py` and hitting <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> shuts it off.

BUT - if I hit access that `'/'` route via the browser once or more, and a moment later try to kill the script in the same manner, then it would take about 10 seconds of nothing until it responds and is finally killed.

**Why is this happening? How can I shut the server off immediately each time for continuous and quick development?**

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if your goal is continuous and quick development, then you can change flask's configuration.

Best solution for your problem would be setting the `DEBUG` setting to **True**. If `DEBUG` is set to True, then flask will **automatically reload** the server on code changes.

There are a few ways to do this but the easiest one(because you said you are a beginner) is to pass the `debug` argument to `app.run()`

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/') 
def index():
    return '<h1>Hello World!</h1>'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: thanks, your suggestion was helpful + it also led me to the understanding that Flask is not just a HTTP server library as I thought, but rather a micro-framework with more features than that.